# Proving injectivity of a multivariable function

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Let $I$ denote the interval $(0,\infty)$, we define the function $f:I^2\to I^2$ by,
$$f(x,y)=\left({\Gamma(4x+y)\Gamma(y)\over {\Gamma(2x+y)}^2},{\Gamma(4x+y)\Gamma(2x+y)\over {\Gamma(3x+y)}^2}\right)$$
where, $\Gamma()$ is the gamma function.

It has been observed numerically that this function is injective in its domain, but how can we prove that?